# Jasmine + TypeScript, can`t find the withArgs () method of the Spy class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

[According to the Jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/Spy.html), the Spy object has a method withArgs ()

```
spyOn (someObj, 'func'). withArgs (1, 2, 3) .and.returnValue (42);
```

I can`t find this method in the version adapted for TypeScript. My project was created with angular-cli(ng new), Jasmine was provided from the box. When I try to call the withArgs() method, Visual Code writes to me that this method does not exist in the Spy class...

Comment: The [`@types/jasmine`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jasmine/v/2.8.8) node package seems to be out of date with the current latest version of Jasmine, 3.1. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/27938) on the GitHub repo so it can be addressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that you are either using an old version of jasmine, or an old version of the jasmine typings library. This particular method was introduced in [Jasmine 3.0](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/Spy.html).  Notice that in the [Jasmine 2.9 docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.9/Spy.html), the method does not exist.

All you need to do is update your Jasmine and jasmine typings libraries. Assuming you are using npm, you can do something like this:

```
npm i -D jasmine@latest jasmine-core@latest @types/jasmine@latest
```

This updates all jasmine related libraries to their latest version and saves it as devDependencies.

Comment: though your answer is correct - the problem here is that the typings are missing this specific method: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/27938

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating the Jasmine library was no option within the delivery time span due to company policies. Hence I could not use withArgs.
I solved it by using `callFake` and manually check the argument there.Like this:

```
mockAuthenticationService = jasmine.createSpyObj<AuthenticationService>('authenticationService', ['hasPermission']);
mockAuthenticationService.hasPermission.and.callFake((permission) => {
  return (permission === 'MyPermission');
});
```